# What is the reduction factor or decrement of an initial velocity that is required to travel a certain distance in a discrete time problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Assume I have an object that moves with an initial velocity $V_0$, and I need this object to travel a certain distance $D$ then stops completely by decreasing its velocity with a reduction factor $r$ **or** decrement $dv$ each time step $ms$. How can I calculate $r$ and $dv$?

**Note:**
This question is a mathematical clarification to my solution of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285998/calculate-deceleration-based-on-velocity-and-grid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first case, the objects will require - theoretically - infinity time steps to travel the distance $D$, as the velocity will never actually reach zero using successive multiplication. The velocity at any time step $V_i$ can be calculated using this formula:
$V_i=r^i V_0$
The distance travelled through that time step can be calculated as:
$\Delta D_i= r^i V_0 ms$
The total distance travelled through the required infinite time steps can be calculated as:
$D=∑_0^\infty r^i V_0 ms=V_0 ms ∑_0^\infty r^i =\frac{V_0ms}{1-r}$
Finally, $r$ can be evaluated as:
$r=1-\frac{V_0 ms}{D}$

For the second case, the required time steps needed will be finite and estimated as:
$n=\frac{V_0}{dv}$
The velocity at any time step $V_i$ can be calculated using this formula:
$V_i=V_0-i dv$
The distance travelled through that time step can be calculated as:
$\Delta D_i= (V_0-i dv) ms$
The total distance travelled through the required $n$ time steps can be calculated as:
$D=∑_0^{n-1} (V_0-i dv) ms=ms ∑_0^{n-1} (V_0-i dv)=ms[nV_0-\frac{n(n-1)}2 dv]=msn(V_0-\frac{n-1}2 dv)$
By substituering the value of $n$:
$D=\frac{msV_0}{dv}(V_0-\frac{V_0-dv}2)=\frac {ms V_0}{2dv} (V_0+dv)$
Solving to get the value of $dv$:
$2Ddv=msV_0 (V_0+dv)=msV_0^2+msV_0 dv$
$dv(2D-msV_0 )=msV_0^2$
$dv=\frac{msV_0^2}{2D-msV_0}$
**Note:**
The travelled distance for the second case may not always be $D$ as the required number of steps $n$ calculated from the final formula will be:
$n=\frac{V_0}{dv}=\frac{2D-msV_0}{msV_0}=\frac{2D}{msV_0}-1$
and this value will only be an integer if the value $\frac{2D}{msV_0}$ is an integer, otherwise there will be an extra travelled distance $eD$ that can be calculated as follows.
The value $\frac{2D}{msV_0}-1$ will contain an integer part $h$ and a real part $f$, so the value $h$ can be expressed as:
$h=\frac{2D}{msV_0}-1-f$
The distance travelled before the $hth$ time step can be evaluated as:
$D_h=∑_0^{h-1} (V_0-i dv) ms=msh(V_0-\frac{h-1}2 dv)=(\frac{2D}{V_0}-ms-msf)[V_0-(\frac {2D-2msV_0-msV_0f}{2msV_0})(\frac{msV_0^2}{2D-msV_0})]=(\frac{2D}{V_0}-ms-msf)[V_0-\frac {(2D-2msV_0-msV_0f)V_0}{4D-2msV_0}]=(\frac{2D}{V_0}-ms-msf)(\frac {2D+msV_0f}{4D-2msV_0})V_0=(2D-msV_0-msV_0f)(\frac {2D+msV_0f}{4D-2msV_0})$
The velocity at the $hth$ time step is:
$V_h=V_0-h dv=V_0-(\frac{2D}{msV_0}-1-f)(\frac{msV_0^2}{2D-msV_0})=V_0-(\frac{2D-msV_0-msV_0f}{msV_0})(\frac{msV_0^2}{2D-msV_0})=V_0(1-\frac{2D-msV_0-msV_0f}{2D-msV_0})=\frac{msV_0^2f}{2D-msV_0}$
The distance travelled through that time step is:
$\Delta D_h=\frac{msV_0^2f}{2D-msV_0}ms=\frac{ms^2V_0^2f}{2D-msV_0}$
So the total travelled distance will be expressed as:
$D_t=D_h+\Delta D_h=\frac{4D^2-ms^2V_0^2f^2-2msV_0D+ms^2V_0^2f}{4D-2msV_0}$
Hence the extra travelled distance will be:
$eD=D_t-D=\frac{-ms^2V_0^2f^2+ms^2V_0^2f}{4D-2msV_0}=\frac{ms^2V_0^2f(1-f)}{4D-2msV_0}$
To get rid of this error, the velocity of the last time step $V_h$ should be reduced to this value:
$V_{h mod}=\frac{D-D_h}{ms}=\frac{msV_0^2f(1+f)}{4D-2msV_0}$
**Special case:**
If the value of $\frac{2D}{msV_0}-1$ is less than one, that means the object in its first time step will travel $msV_0$ which is more that the required distance $D$. Therefore, the initial velocity $V_0$ should not exceed $\frac D {ms}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more natural to have a constant deceleration, so the velocity decreases by a fixed amount each time step.  It will then stop in a finite time.  I think the simplest approach is to have an analytic formula for the position as a function of time, which you then round at each time step to find where to plot it.  For a particle that starts at position $s_0$ with velocity $v_0$ and has a fixed (in your case, negative) acceleration $a$ the position is
$$s=s_0+v_0t+\frac 12at^2$$
If $v_0 \gt 0, a\lt 0$ the time to zero velocity is $t=-\frac {v_0}a$ and the distance covered is $D=-\frac {v_0^2}{2a}$  You can use this to compute $a=-\frac{v_0^2}D$, then compute the position $s$ at any time and round it to find where to plot the object.

Comment: This could have worked if it was a continuous time problem, but the original question I was addressing was using time steps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285998/calculate-deceleration-based-on-velocity-and-grid

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef:  I see time steps as a window on the world, so if we have a continuous view of the world we just take snapshots at each time step.  It is like a movie camera filming a scene.  You take a picture every $\frac 1{30}$ or so seconds and run the movie.  It doesn't mean the world works in time steps, just that that is what we see.  If I were writing a video game every object would have a position that was a function of continuous time that would be sampled at the frame rate to decide where to portray it. There are other approaches.  You have shown some things OP didn't think of

Comment: This could be a good possibility too, however, I think it will produce a small error as the velocity within each frame will be constant in the original question.

Comment: @AbdelAzizAbdelLatef:  in my model, the velocity is also a continuous function of time.  Imagine a space combat game.  Objects are created with some velocity at some time.  If they have mass there is a continuous acceleration due to gravity.  The program models the motion to some acceptable accuracy, which may involve smaller time steps than the display or analytical formulas.  At each display time step it decides where to show each object.  I didn't see my answer as saying something was wrong with yours.  The pair of them may help OP clarify the situation.